# Is it possible to change the colour of legend elements in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to find ways to changes the colour of the legend that is related to the size

```
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt))+
  geom_point(aes(color = cyl, size = qsec, shape = as.factor(gear)))
p
```

[image]

Now all the circles are black and I want to change their color to grey and my picture look like this.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help and for reading this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `guides()` to adjust the `size` option in your plot with the desired color:

```
#Code
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt))+
  geom_point(aes(color = cyl, size = qsec, shape = as.factor(gear)))+
  guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = "gray")))
```

Output:

[image]